# simple way to send value from javascript to python back-end in streamlit

Tags: javascript, python, streamlit

I've used a [st.components.v1.iframe](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/components/components-api#render-an-iframe-url) to integrate an authentication mechanism that sends back a token to the parent if the user is allowed to authenticate, the iframe content looks like this:

```
    <script src="remote/auth.js"></script>
    <script>
      token = window.getAuth();
      parent.postMessage(token, '*');
    </script>
```

and in the streamlit app:

```
from streamlit.components.v1 import html, iframe
html("""
<script>
    parent.window.addEventListener('message', e => {
        const key = e.message ? 'message' : 'data';
        const token = e[key];
        parent.window.token = token;
    },false);
</script>
""")
iframe("RemoteIframeLocation")
```

Now what I want is to send back the `parent.window.token` to the python back-end in order to grant  access to users based on the token.

I'm aware that basically this should be possible with [bi-directional streamlit components](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/components/components-api#create-a-bi-directional-component), but it seems like it's way too complicated and an overkill for my use case where I only need to send one value !

Comment: Have you found an answer? Trying to fix a very similar problem

Comment: @Maria I was able to get the token with [streamlit-javascript](https://pypi.org/project/streamlit-javascript/) package with `return_value = st_javascript('window.parent.token')` but the issue is that sometimes the app runs that line before the token generation and hence I got an empty `return_value `.

Comment: Could you please paste your code to see in detail how you managed this?

Comment: @AlejandroMonsalveKrause I've posted the updated answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to this issue using the [streamlit_javascript package](https://github.com/thunderbug1/streamlit-javascript) and basic retry logic:

```
from streamlit_javascript import st_javascript
import time

while True:
    token = st_javascript('parent.window.token')
    if token:
        break
    time.sleep(1)
```

I guess this could be done cleaner using some JS code to await the reception of the token, but this is good enough for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Create a WebSocket server, the server will listen for incoming token messages from the iframe and handle them. After receiving the token from the iframe, try to process it as needed within the handle_token function.

Comment: Please post descriptive answer. Eg How to create websocket server using python etc.